# child component did not load data from parent

Tags: angular

**customer.component.html**

**customer.component.ts**

```
import { CustomerService } from './../../_services/customer.service';
import { Address } from './../../_models/address.model';
import { Customer } from './../../_models/customer.model';
import { Component, OnInit, Input, Output, EventEmitter, ChangeDetectionStrategy } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-customer',
  templateUrl: './customer.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./customer.component.css'],
  changeDetection: ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush
})
export class CustomerComponent implements OnInit {

  customers: Customer[]=[];

  selectedCustomer: Customer;
  constructor(
    private _customerService: CustomerService,
  ) { }

  ngOnInit(): void {

    this.getCustomers();

    // this._customerService.getAll().subscribe(
    //   response => {
    //     return response;
    //   },
    //   error => {
    //   return [];
    //   }
    // );


  }


  newCustomerHandler() {
    this.selectedCustomer = <Customer>{
      firm: 4,
      name: null,
      phone: null,
      email: null,
      dob: null,
      occupation: null,
      address: {
        line1: null,
        line2: null,
        city: null,
        pincode: null,
        states: null,
        country: 'India'
      },
      gst: null,
      pan: null,
      city: null,
      gender: 'MALE',
    };
  }

  selectedCustomerHandler(custoemrId: number) {
    this.selectedCustomer = Object.assign({}, this.customers.find((customer: Customer) => customer.id === custoemrId));
  }


  saveCustomerHandler(customer: Customer) {

    if (!customer.id) {
      // Add a new product
      console.log('Add new Customer1');
      console.log(customer);

      this._customerService.create(customer).subscribe(
        (response: Customer) => {
          alert('Added Successfully');
          this.selectedCustomer = null;
        },
        error => {
          alert('Failed to add');
        }
      );
    } else {
      console.log('Update Customer');
    }
   
  }


  getCustomers() {

    this._customerService.getAll().subscribe(
      response => {
        this.customers = response;
      },
      error => {
        return [];
      }
    );
  }
}
```

**customer-list.component.html**

```
<h2>Manage Customer</h2>
<div class="customer-list">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-9">
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-3" style="float:right;">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-block btn-primary" (click)="onNewClick.emit()">CREATE NEW CUSTOMER</button>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="table-responsive">
        <table class="table m-0">
          <thead>
          <tr>

            <th>Name</th>
            <th>Gender</th>
            <th>Email</th>
            <th>Phone</th>
            <th>PAN</th>
            <th>GST</th>
            <th>Occupation</th>
            <th>DOB</th>
            <th>City</th>
          </tr>
          </thead>
          <tbody>

            <tr *ngFor="let customer of customers" >
              <td>{{customer.name}}</td>
              <td>{{customer.gender}}</td>
              <td>{{customer.email}}</td>
              <td>{{customer.phone}}</td>
              <td>{{customer.pan}}</td>
              <td>{{customer.gst}}</td>
              <td>{{customer.occupation}}</td>
              <td>{{customer.dob | date}}</td>
              <td>{{customer.city}}</td>
            </tr>
          </tbody>
        </table>
      </div>
  </div>
```

**cusotmer-list.component.ts**

```
import { Address } from './../../_models/address.model';
import { Customer } from './../../_models/customer.model';
import { Component, OnInit, Input, Output, ChangeDetectionStrategy, EventEmitter } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-customer-list',
  templateUrl: './customer-list.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./customer-list.component.css'],
  changeDetection: ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush
})
export class CustomerListComponent implements OnInit {

  @Input() customers: Array<Customer>;
  @Output() onSelected: EventEmitter<number> = new EventEmitter<number>();
  @Output() onNewClick: EventEmitter<void> = new EventEmitter<void>();
  constructor() { }
  ngOnInit(): void {
    console.log(this.customers);
  }
}
```

customer.component.htmls is my parent component, I am sending data to child component customer-list.component.html  but child component is not receiving data. Parent component gets data from rest API which is pass to child component.

Answer (score 1):

change  CustomerListComponent.ts

```
ngOnInit(): void {
  console.log(this.customers);
}
```

to

```
ngOnChanges(): void {
   console.log(this.customers);
}
```

Comment: this is not working for me, console prints  customers: SimpleChange
currentValue: []
firstChange: true
previousValue: undefined
__proto__: Object
__proto__: Object

Answer (score 0):

Angular sees `CustomerComponent` and `CustomerListComponent` as two separate components, not as parent-child components, because you are not calling `<app-customer-list>` anywhere in `CustomerComponent`. To make it a child component put the component tag in `customer-list.component.html` where you'd like to render it.

If you want to pass data between unrelated components like these then you will have to create a [service that is shared](https://jasonwatmore.com/post/2019/02/07/angular-7-communicating-between-components-with-observable-subject) between them and use a Subject to pass data.

Comment: my customer.component.html contains                                                                          
 <app-customer-list [customers]="customers"
    (onSelected)="selectedCustomerHandler($event)"
    (onNewClick)="newCustomerHandler()"   >
    </app-customer-list>

Comment: Oh, didn't notice. It is not rendering in the post. Are you sure the service is not failing? Can you put console logs and confirm? It could be the observable is failing and assigning empty array to `customers`.

Comment: service is working properly , it returns array customers within parent (customer.component.html).                                                                                             but in cutomer-list.component.ts within ngOnit   console prints undefined